# While accessing json file the browser shows error (Angular JS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, google-chrome, firefox

When I have included the todos.json file in the javascript it is showing this error.
The browser i have used is firefox and in chrome it is showing Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
the error in firefox is below

```
Error: Access to restricted URI denied
fg/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js:99:1
r@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js:95:367
m/g<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js:93:8
e/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js:126:404
uf/this.$get</m.prototype.$eval@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js:141:43
uf/this.$get</m.prototype.$digest@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js:138:132
uf/this.$get</m.prototype.$apply@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js:141:339
Ac/c/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js:21:42
h/<.invoke@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js:41:293
Ac/c@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js:20:1
Ac@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js:21:259
fe@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js:20:69
@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js:306:372
m.Callbacks/j@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js:2:27304
m.Callbacks/k.fireWith@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js:2:28122
.ready@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js:2:29954
J@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js:2:30320
```

```js
var App = angular.module('App', []);

App.controller('TodoCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('../todos.json')
    .then(function(res) {
      $scope.todos = res.data;
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <!-- all the script and javascript file are included-->
</head>
<title>Discussion</title>

<body ng-app="App">
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
        {{todo.text}} - <em>{{todo.done}}</em>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: are you running off the file protocol or http? If yes, you should be running a local server.

Comment: without local server
is there any other way ??

Comment: It is really simple to run a local server with node or python or IIS. Only way around it is to change your browser settings to allow local file access.